# Should I escape the condition for my rails find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

OK so i have this condition

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:state] = params[:state] if params[:state]
@apps = current.apps.paginate(:include => :user, :conditions => conditions, :order => "users.first_name, users.last_name")
```

and my routes file has

```
 map.apps_wishlist '/apps/wishlist', :controller => 'apps', :action => 'index', :state => 'wishlist'
```

Since i am sending in the string should i escape the sql somehow for security reasons and if so how is the best way to do that

Someone suggested they think the params[:state] should be escaped when put into the SQL query for security reasons

Answer (score 5):

They don't know what they're talking about. As long as you do either

```
SomeModel.where(:conditions => {:state => params[:state]})
#or
SomeModel.find(:conditions => {:state => params[:state]})
#or
SomeModel.where("state = ?", params[:state])
```

ActiveRecord will handle all the escaping itself, so the code you've given above is fine/ The only case it doesn't cover is if you were building up the sql entirely on your own, i.e. *don't* do

```
SomeModel.where("state = #{params[:state]}")
```

If you're using `find_by_sql`, `execute` and so on then you are also responsible for escaping. Don't just take my word for it though - try it! You might also want to look at the rails [security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)